# How do I specify a picture-box through adding two strings?

Tags: c#

I have a pictureBox that I want to specify by combining two other strings. Lets say the pictureBox was called Tile20 what would I do? How do I make this work?:

```
if("Tile" + "20".Tag == "Hello")
{
     rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: No, you need to access the object of `PictureBox` class to do this. Check this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find(string.Concat("Tile","20")).FirstOrDefault();

if (pictureBox != null)
{
   if (pictureBox.Tag == "Hello")
   {
     rest of the code...
   }
}
```

Comment: Close, but not quite right. The `Find` method returns an *array*, not a single `PictureBox` object.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the feedback the code is now edited !